# Ошибка в консоли Avoid mutating a prop directly

Tags: vue.js

Вылетает ошибка в консоли:
[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "hover"
Никак не получается исправить.

HTML

```
<div id="body">
  <div class="gallery">
    <div is="item" 
         v-for="(item, index) in items" 
         v-bind="item">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
```

JS

```
;(function(){
    'use strict';

    Vue.component('item', {
        template: `
            <div id="item" v-on:mouseenter="show" v-on:mouseleave="hide" class="item a">
                <div class="hover-strip" v-bind:class="{ visible: hover }"></div>
            </div>
        `,
        props: ['hover'],
        data () {
            return {

            }
        },
        methods: {
            show: function (event) {
                this.hover = true;
            },
            hide: function (event) {
                this.hover = false;
            }
        }
    })


    new Vue({
        el: '#body',
        data: function () {
            return {
                items: [
                    {
                        hover: false
                    },
                    {
                        hover: false
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    });


}());
```

Код на jsfiddle.net https://jsfiddle.net/ngk675qh/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Добавьте локальное состояние для свойства `hover` в `data`

```
data () {
  return {
      hoverLocal: this.hover
  }
},
```

И в своем компоненте ссылайтесь на него, а не на `hover`.

Дело в том, что `Vue.js` практикует подход `one way data flow` то-бишь изменение свойств родителей дочерними компонентами напрямую запрещено. Об этом `Vue` в данном случае и сообщает, то, что свойство `hover` у вас есть, но изменить его из дочернего компонента он не сможет.

Если вам все таки необходимо изменять свойства родителя из дочернего элемента: почитайте про [Sync](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-sync), [Шину данных](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8) или [vuex](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html)

Comment: `Vue.component('item', {
 template: 
  <div id="item" v-on:mouseenter="show" v-on:mouseleave="hide" class="item a">
   <div class="hover-strip" v-bind:class="{ visible: hoverLocal }"></div>
  </div>
 ,
 props: ['hoverLocal'],
 data () {
  return {
      hoverLocal: this.hover
     }
 },
 methods: {
  show: function (event) {
   this.hoverLocal = true;
  },
  hide: function (event) {
   this.hoverLocal = false;
  }
 }
})`                            поправил, но ошибка та же, плюс "The data property "hoverLocal" is already declared as a prop. Use prop default value instead."

Comment: Не надо объявлять `hoverLocal` как `prop`. Оставьте там `hover`